# How do I read two inputs one after another in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've only been able to figure out one input

```
var readline = require('readline');

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', readLine);

function readLine (line) {
  if (line !== "\n") {
    var firstNum = parseInt(line.toString().split(' ')[0], 10);
    process.exit();
  }
}
```

I've tried:
 - Calling rl again
 - Creating another var similar to rl
 - And just plain old hacking around for the last hour

I'm trying to be able to read two. For example, if I were adding corresponding numbers between two inputs

**Input:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 3 4 7 11
```

**Output would be:**

```
7 5 7 11 16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling process.exit() after the first read. That'll end everything and no more code will be executed.

You have to store your first line, then read another line, and then you can end the process.

Check the code next. I've declared `firstNum` and `secondNum` **outside** the function. Then I check if `firstNum` was already assigned (if not, it's the first read, else it's the second read). On second read, I do a console.log to check what's stored and I finally exit the process.

```
var readline = require('readline');

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', readLine);

var firstNum, secondNum;

function readLine (line) {
  if (line !== "\n") {
    if (!firstNum) {
        firstNum = line;
    } else {
        secondNum = line;
        console.log(sum(firstNum, secondNum));
        process.exit();
    }
  }
}

function sum(str1, str2) {
    var n1 = str1.split(' ').map(function(n){ return parseInt(n); });
    var n2 = str2.split(' ').map(function(n, i){ return parseInt(n) + n1[i]; });
    return n2.join(' ');
}
```

You can replace the `console.log` call with your logic to split the strings and sum the numbers before displaying them.

**EDIT** just added a `sum(s1, s2)` function that does what you want. Check it!

Comment: Thanks for being so elaborate! Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You exit after reading a line. You can't read the second line if your program is not running any more.

```
var readline = require('readline');

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false
});

var lines = [];
rl.on('line', readLine);

function addLines(l1, l2) {
  return l1.map(function(e, i) {
    return e + l2[i];
  });
}

function readLine(line) {
  var numbers = line.toString().split(' ').map(function(x) {
    return parseInt(x);
  });
  lines.push(numbers);
  if (lines.length == 2) {
    var sumLine = addLines(lines[0], lines[1]);
    console.log(sumLine);
    process.exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I only selected the other answer because it went into a little more detail.